# Dynamic Page Replacing Content joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, extension-request

This is the first question, sorry if it is inadequate.
Before working with joomla I used to use the "Dynamic Page Replacing Content" script by CSSTRICKS, with a few modifications.
A few months ago I started using Joomla!3 and I tried to implement the script.
It loads the content, but the back and forward buttons (the history of the browser) doesn't work.
Is there any joomla extension that makes the same work, or is there any script I can use to achieve the same effect. 
Basically what I want is to load the content to a certain div without reloading the entire page, with joomla.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**NoNumber ReReplacer**

With ReReplacer you can replace whatever you want in your entire site.

It can work on the entire output of your site, so you can also do replacements in things like the meta tags.

Some ideas where you can use ReReplacer for:

Create your own custom tags ([mytag]some text[/mytag] becomes some text).
Tweak the output of Joomla! without changing the core joomla or extension files.
Filter bad words on your site.
Temporarily hide text from your website, without actually removing it.
Remove redundant whitespace from your code, making your website load faster.
Use abbreviations in your content and replace them with the full text (J! becomes Joomla!, COMP becomes My Very Long Company Name®).
Quickly place whole blocks of text by only typing one word. Like you can use [stats] and replace it with a piece of Google Statistics code. Or [footer] to put a fixed bit of text under articles. You can change the replacement in one place (in ReReplacer) and your whole website is updated!
etc...
You have the ability to use powerful regular expressions to search and replace. This opens up endless possibilities. You can do virtually everything with ReReplacer.

Reference: http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer

Comment: I second this. Rereplacer is a life savor for me. There are times when an html override just won't cut it and I have to override the output of something in the core of a component or module. This is the tool for that job.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I wanted! Every time I navigate thru the site, I want to load and replace the content (article component and modules) without leaving the initial page; I don't want to replace html directly. But thanks anyway

Comment: If you want to replace without leaving the initial page, it must be a dynamic... on Javascript side.

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm trying to do. With "Dynamic Page Replacing Content" script by CSSTRICKS I can load the content, but the history browser buttons don't work. They work in the demo version, without joomla, but in the joomla version they don't work.

Comment: There are a lot of subject to check. It may a CSS or a Javascript issue. At the end, not related with Joomla itself.

Comment: what I'd like to know it's related to joomla! As I said I'd like to know if there's any joomla plugin that does the same thing!